# Issue with transcode video using MediaTranscoder

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, uwp

Currently I'm developing a video converter (UWP application) using Windows.Media.Transcoding.MediaTranscoder. And I'm faced with the next issue, - I'm losing subtitles and metadata after transcoding a video. How I can set subtitles for video manually? Can I set subtitles using Windows.Storage.FileProperties.VideoProperties?

Thanks for any info.